# the meaning of sensory experience

Tags: meaning

I'm not sure if "sensory experience" is a term. I googled it a bit and got some hits.

> Sticking a knife into a toaster will give you a **sensory experience**, but so will smelling a rose. Stick with the rose.

[source](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sensory)

I am aware of the concept of senses: taste, sight, smell, touch/felt, hearing.

I guess I understand the meaning of **sensory experience** as per that quotation.

I'd just like to know whether the happiness of successful solving a math question is a sensory experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the happiness resulting from the successful solving of a math problem is not termed a "sensory experience." Rather, it is sometimes called an "emotional high," because happiness is an emotion.

The meaning of "sensory experience" is an experience that stimulates the senses. The jolt from the shock of sticking a knife in the toaster is a powerful stimulation of the nervous system for touch. The sweet scent of a rose stimulates the sense of smell, while a clap of thunder stimulates the sense of hearing. All those things are "sensory experiences." I rather doubt, though, that these are the sensory experiences that people write stories about.

The more sensational sensory experiences that stories are written about and movies are made of are ventures like mountain climbing or skiing on very challenging cliffs or other physical pursuits and extreme sports that challenge the body and its abilities. The people who participate in these enjoy the sensations experienced as they pursue their adventures.

Some sensory experiences they may enjoy are:

- the vast vistas from mountaintops (sight),
- the pull on muscles stretched to the limit (feel),
- the hissing of skis whizzing down the slope (hearing)
- the feel of the wind on their skin (feel, touch)
- the smell of roast, fresh-baked bread and good wine (smell)
- the taste of a home-cooked meal (taste)

Why do we call these events "sensory experiences"? Is it not the rich flavour of the roast or red wine that stimulates the taste buds, for example? Or  pollen from the rose that stimulates my nose, resulting in an experience called "the delicate fragrance of roses"? (I stole that exquisite wording from your comment below.) Of course it is! You're right. But having the pollen or flavour stimulate the senses constitutes an experience in and of itself.

[Experience Defined](https://www.google.com/search?q=experience%20definition&oq=experience%20de&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i57j0l4j69i60.6895j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> noun
>
> practical contact with and observation of facts or events. "he
>   had already learned his lesson by painful experience"
>
> verb
>
> encounter or undergo (an event or occurrence). "the company is
>   experiencing difficulties"

Experience is when something happens to us, or when we go through something, something that is lived and not imagined. For example, when you experience pollen tickling your nose, the pollen ticking your nose is happening to you. You are experiencing it. It is your experience that pollen tickles your nose, and that when it is the pollen of a rose you smell a "delicate fragrance."

The "delicate fragrance of the rose" is, however, a sensory experience as opposed to an intellectual experience because you experienced or encountered it via the sense of smell. In your Opening Question you list "smell" as one of the five senses, along with taste, touch, hearing, and seeing. Thus, the things we experience or encounter through one or more of the five senses are called "sensory experiences." We might, perhaps, also call them "sensory encounters." That is what I understand from the definition you linked to; I also found it when I Googled "sensory experience definition."

Sensory experiences, if they are very pleasant, are often accompanied with an emotional high, very similar to the emotional high one experiences from successfully solving a difficult math problem. For sure the people who are into extreme sports love it or they would never work so hard in such dangerous situations outside of search and rescue, when no lives are at stake.

Thus, you can see how sensory experiences and emotional highs can go hand in hand. However, solving a math problem successfully is seldom considered a sensory experience even though it gives you the same emotional high that extreme sports gives to others. I would consider the solving of math problems an intellectual experience.

Comment: Such a great work! Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. I might have some difficulties on understanding the clause "experience that stimulates the senses". I guess what stimulates the senses is another thing, rather than experience. For example, pollen stimulates my nose, resulting in some experience called "the delicate fragrance of roses"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your question is very clear. I added quite a bit to my answer. Does that explain?