# express the meaning of "emotional high" in a more formal way

Tags: vocabulary

A nice answer to [the meaning of sensory experience](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/244175/109190) says

> the happiness resulting from the successful solving of a math problem is not termed a "sensory experience." Rather, it is sometimes called an "**emotional high**", because happiness is an emotion.

That answer is clear and easy to understand.

"[Emotion High](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Emotion%20High)" seems to be some kind of street language. I just worried if it is acceptable to use the phrase "**emotional high**" in some more formal situations, such as IELTS test?

I guess "passionate" and "enthusiastic" are acceptable for IELTS test, though I concerned they are a lit bit stronger than the emotion resulting from the successful solving of a math problem.

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: delighted, thrilled

Comment: I would also suggest "elated" and "ecstatic."

Answer (score -1):

Maybe "mildly euphoric" would fit. Or "mild euphoria" for a noun form.